# How to set the position of the table view cell because the tab bar block the cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

The structure of my storyboard is:

a--b--c,d,e

a is a navigation controller
b is a tab bar controller
c,d,e are tab views
c is a table view controller contains about ten cells.
when i scrolled up, the position of the last cell and the tab bar is overlapped.
How to set the position of the last cell so that it can lay up the tab bar so that we can touch it?
Thank you.

Comment: In storyboard, select table view, then on the top menu bar of Xcode, editor menu, go to pin, Bottom space to superview

Comment: when i select the table view, the bottom space to superview item cannot be selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your tableview controller, the main goal is to decrease your table height.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    CGFloat tabBarHeight = self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height;
    CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
    frame.size.height -= tabBarHeight;
    self.tableView.frame = frame;
}
```

The above code will result in a gray tabBar. And each time switching tab will decrease table height, so moving the above code to viewDidLoad, and set the tabBar translucent to NO.

**Solution 1:**

```
CGFloat tabBarHeight = self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height;
CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
frame.size.height -= tabBarHeight;
self.view.frame = frame;
self.tabBarController.tabBar.translucent = NO;
```

Alternatively, you can configure tableView's contentInset in viewDidLoad.

**Solution 2:**

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGRectGetHeight(self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame), 0.0f);
```

Comment: Yes,those code can solve my problem.But strange thing happened, the tab bar background become gray while i change to another tab view the tab bar background is white?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the TableView height is incorrect.
You have to set the constraints of the TableView so the bottom of the tableView to be at the beginning of the TabBar.

Comment: Do you mean that i set the height of the bottom cell to be large enough so it can be at the beginning of the tabbar? but it is a little weird because the separate line is laied far behind the context of the bottom cell

Comment: NO the table view height is too big. You have to make the Tableview shorter.